# add counter to the n combinations of javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations, counter

This program should output a number of combinations possible of elements from array. What do i fail to do is to add in the left side a counter for each combination possible. Something like "001" for the first combination , "002" for the second and so on, to the last. I tried to do that with a for-loop and while-do in many ways but any attempt was a failure.

```js
function combine(a, b, c) {

  if (b === 0) {
    console.log(three.join(" "));
    return;
  }

  for (var i = c; i <= a.length - b; i++) {
    three[three.length - b] = a[i];
    combine(a, b - 1, i + 1);
  }

}
const vegetables = ["carrot", "tomatoes", "potatoes", "celery", "pepper"];
const three = [];
three.length = 4;

combine(vegetables, three.length, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `padStart` to generate what you are looking for. Something like this

```js
const vegetables = ["carrot", "tomatoes", "potatoes", "celery", "pepper"];
const three = [];
three.length = 4;
let counter = 1;
function combine(a, b, c) {
  if (b === 0) {
    const counterForPrint = (counter++).toString().padStart(3, "0");
    console.log(`${counterForPrint} ${three.join(" ")}`);
    return;
  }
  for (let i = c; i <= a.length - b; i++) {
    three[three.length - b] = a[i]; combine(a, b - 1, i + 1);
  }
}

combine(vegetables, three.length, 0);
```

By the way there are libraries which you could use to generate combinations. It makes things very clear and let you focus on actual logic. Something like this

```
const Combinatorics = require("js-combinatorics");
const vegetables = ["carrot", "tomatoes", "potatoes", "celery", "pepper"];

const possibleCombinations = Combinatorics.permutation(vegetables);
let counter = 1;
possibleCombinations.forEach(element => {
  const counterForPrint = (counter++).toString().padStart(3, "0");
  console.log(`${counterForPrint} ${element}`);
});
```